# Is the current iso broken

Tags: release-loki

I'm trying to install Loki. I've downloaded the `.iso` file, but it does not show up in Rufus or Unetbootin when browsing for an .iso.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly related to Elementary OS.

Comment: @AxelAdvento As they asked it on [elementaryos.se] can't we assume they are trying to install elementary? They've even tagged it "loki".

Comment: @user3 I'd agree we might be able to help (even though I know nothing about Rufus or Unetbootin) but ideally we at least need a version. Without a version of the ISO, this question will become confusing as `the current` is not a useful reference. How often do EOS update the ISO?

Comment: You have added an answer at any rate, hopefully they accept.

Comment: @SamMorrowDrums do the isos have visible versions? When I download I just get a nondescript iso file.

Comment: Hmmm I honestly don't know, maybe a question for Daniel Foré?

Answer (score 1):

You might be trying to find it in the dropdown list - unfortunately elementaryOS is not in that.

[image]

You have to click the browse button - the <kbd>...</kbd>.

[image]

Navigate to the file (probably in your downloads folder), and open it.

[image]

If that doesn't work, could you edit your question to add a little more information?